# Async.waterfall inside a promise queue fails to show the indented behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, q, async.js

A promise queue (through q library) is implemented.

PQFn1-(then)- PQFn2-(then)-....

The PQFn1 passes an array of values to a callback function(implemented using Q.defer), which returns a result.
So the flow switches from PQFn1 to ProcessResultFn([values])
Inside ProcessResultFn-

```
ProcessResultFn(values){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

async.map(values,FetchResult,function(err,res){
      if (err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
      return deferred.promise;
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(res);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
})
}

Function FetchResult(value,done){
async.waterfall(Fn1,Fn2,Fn3,done);
}
}
```

The flow works fine till the call reaches Fn1. However as soon as Fn1 calls cb()- to pass on call to Fn2. The flow switches to PQFn2 of promise queue, without even waiting from result from ProcessResultFn.
The call to Fn2 and then to Fn3 is also executed later on, when event loop picks it up(I logged it). However the initial result from PQFn1 to PQFn2 is always returned undefined. 
Can someone please explain why this happens.

Comment: Can you include text of `FN1` at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the promise from the `ProcessResultFn` function, not from the `async.map` callback:

```
ProcessResultFn(values) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    async.map(values,FetchResult,function(err,res){
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(res);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

(And of course I recommend not to use async.js when you could have promises right away, so rather promisify `Fn1`, `Fn2` and `Fn3` and use simply `Q.all(values.map(value => Fn1P(value).then(Fn2P).then(Fn3P)))`.)

Comment: Yes. This got it working.
@Bergi I am new to promises, so my natural instinct was to right the return call(in this case return deferred.promise) inside the callback function, else it would be called prior to the execution of async function.
Why is it different in this case?

Comment: Because `return` works only immediately, and *not* inside asynchronous functions (just like with usual asynchronous callbacks). Promises are a data structures that allows us to return a *meaningful* value there even if nothing has yet happened.